# How many different statistics packages use GPL (Graphical Programming Language)?

Tags: data-visualization, spss, software

QUESTION: How many different statistics packages use GPL?

BACKGROUND: Most of what I am finding regarding GPL ([Graphical Programming Language](http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/cl/spss/graph/gpl.html)) is in relation to SPSS. While the literature I've seen indicates GPL was created to produce a cross-platform syntax for graphics, I can't seem to find references indicating that Minitab, R or STATA use GPL as one means of producing graphics.

While I am learning GPL because vanilla SPSS produces wretched graphics, my learning process would be psychically more easy to endure if I knew GPL was really more widely used.

Comment: Can you explain what is GPL?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that it could also be confused for the more common acronym of General Purpose License.

Comment: GPL implements Leland Wilkinson's "grammar of graphics". R has an implementation in the package `ggplot2`, there are probably others, under differing names.

Comment: GPL in SPSS is Graphics Production (not Programming) Language